NextJS Prisma Invalid client engine type, please use `library` or `binary`
This is the error message I got in the terminal: "TypeError: The "payload" argument must be of type object. Received null"
I am trying to fetch user data like so:
const user = await prisma.user.findMany({
  orderBy: {
    id: 'desc'
  }
});


The solution was to import PrismaClient from @prisma/client instead of @prisma/client/edge.
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

It took me 3 hours to figure out the fix, I have been following prisma docs I don't know why they suggest to import from @prisma/client/edge in their docs https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/accelerate/nextjs-starter/lib/db.ts

That's very strange. I have just one query that just doesn't seem to be working.
I use correct prisma

I had the same issue but I needed to use @prisma/client/edge. The solution for me was that I forgot to set my server action to run on the server using use server.
